# Is there a stable sort that works with partial orders in the standard library?

Tags: swift, sorting, stable-sort, partial-ordering

I have lists of tasks that I want to sort pseudo-topologically. Say, I have something like this:

```
enum Task {
    case a(Int, Int)
    case b(String)
    case c(Bool)
}
```

I require all `a` tasks to be executed before any `b` tasks, and all `b` tasks before all `c` tasks. In addition, all tasks of the same time need to remain in the same order as in the input.

In computer science lingo, what I need is

- a stable sorting algorithm and
- a way to feed it a partial order.

Is there such a thing in the Swift standard library?

Observations:

- `Comparable`, a natural protocol to look at for sorting, requires the order to be total.
- [`sorted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) can be made to work with partial orders, but is not stable.

As an alternative, a topological sorting algorithm would work as well, even though it would do more than I need.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but why can't you define a total order on your type? – Any "a" value is equal to any other "a" value, and less than any "b" value, etc.

Comment: @MartinR I *could* do that if I abused `==` that way. As soon as I need `==` for _real_ equality, implementing `<` as partial order would break the invariants required by `Comparable`.

Comment: I'm afraid not. IIRC, the standard library's sorting algorithms *happen* to be stable, but the documentation explicitly states that there's no guarentee they will be stable.

Comment: @Alexander: The Collection sort method uses Introsort (a variant of Quicksort), which is not stable as far as I know.